# How to show only filtered entries dc.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to create dc.js bar chart with a mini bar chart filter so that when you select on filter it applies it to the bigger chart. But it still shows the rest of entries only they are hidden. I want the x-axis to show the filtered set not complete set. How to do this ? Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipinroshan/tuc8z93L/2/). Result looks like :

[image: Result]

Here's the code

```
var data = [ 
  { 'Expt': 1, 'Run': 1, 'Speed': 85, 'title': 'Title1'  }, 
  { 'Expt': 1, 'Run': 2, 'Speed': 34, 'title': 'Title2'  }, 
  { 'Expt': 1, 'Run': 3,  'Speed': 90, 'title': 'Title3' }, 
  { 'Expt': 1, 'Run': 4, 'Speed': 107, 'title': 'Title4' },
  { 'Expt': 1, 'Run': 5, 'Speed': 85, 'title': 'Title5'  }, 
  { 'Expt': 1, 'Run': 6, 'Speed': 34, 'title': 'Title6'  }, 
  { 'Expt': 1, 'Run': 7,  'Speed': 90, 'title': 'Title7' }, 
  { 'Expt': 1, 'Run': 8, 'Speed': 107, 'title': 'Title8' }
];

var ndx           = crossfilter(data),
runDimension      = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Run;}),
filterDimension   = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Run;}),
speedSumGroup     = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.Speed})
  var chart = dc.barChart("#test");
  chart
    .width(768)
    .height(280)
    .gap(20)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length + 1]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .centerBar(true)
    .renderLabel(true)
    .xAxisPadding(1)
    .yAxisLabel("Y Axis")
    .elasticX(true)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup)
    .renderTitle(true).title(function (d) {
      return 'test: ' + d.value;
        })
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .label(function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return 'test';
        });

  chart.render();
  var chart2 = dc.barChart("#brush");
  chart2
    .width(768)
    .height(180)
    .gap(20)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length + 1]))
    .brushOn(true)
    .centerBar(true)
    .renderLabel(true)
    .xAxisPadding(1)
    .yAxisLabel("Y Axis")
    .elasticX(true)
    .dimension(filterDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup)
        .elasticY(true)
    .renderTitle(true).title(function (d) {
      return 'test: ' + d.value;
        })
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .label(function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return 'test';
        });
  chart2.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would think that `elasticX` would do it, right? But I think what is happening here is that the bins still exist, but are empty. So dc is helpfully "showing your zeros".

I see two potential solutions:

- use the range/focus chart functionality, as demonstrated on the [dc.js stock demo](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) for move and volume. https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#rangechartchart
- More directly answering your question: prefilter out the zeros so that elasticX works as you expect - see second example in this FAQ answer: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted

Comment: I have tried both approaches, both look like working but each one seem to be buggy. range/focus gives uneven bar width, thick overlapping bars, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipinroshan/tuc8z93L/4/). And second approach does not work if I select nothing from brush initially then increase brush selection. See this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipinroshan/tuc8z93L/5/). Maybe you can tell what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you try it with the latest dc.js from master? I put fixes in both areas in July.

Comment: One follow-up is there any way to change behaviour of filtered elements. As you can see it is zeroed out on the chart with brush. I want it to be visible but greyed out. So that its used like a mini-map.

Comment: If you are using the range/focus chart feature, you probably want the two charts to be on the same dimension. A dimension only observes the filters on *other* dimensions, not its own.

Comment: Thanks once again, I got the charts working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipinroshan/tuc8z93L/7/) but not updating [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipinroshan/tuc8z93L/8/). Can you tell what is wrong there ?